# Replace part of screen in android with an activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I know we can replace part of screen(activity) with a certain fragment but I have a pre-formed activity in place. Is there anyway I can replace part of screen with this activity?

P. S I cannot change the activity to a fragment since I need to call this activity from some other place too.

[image]

Each of the tabs at bottom are associated with a fragment except for Keypad. Keypad screen is an activity. When user hits on one of the tabs, the upper part of the screen is replaced with fragment. In the same flow, when I click keypad I wish to replace it by activity. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood what you are saying. Do you want the (1)Activity to open the (2) Activity, and this second Activity has some fragments that replaces the view?

Comment: No, I am already on an activity which has tabs. On clicking of second tab the part of the screen above the tab should be replaced with an activity

Comment: From what I understand only one activity can "exist" at a time. The other "activity" needs to be a fragment. If you could post the code that is preventing this change that would probably benefit you more, as there is very little a activity can do that a fragment can't as they have access to both the containing activity and its context.

Comment: I do get you. However added a photo to have a better understanding, I added a screenshot and described further

Comment: Hum, It's possible to replace to an activity when clicked in keypad, however the activity will appear as full window, if possible show the TabLayout Code.